# Can't stop youtube video from playing on popup close on page with multiple popups from a wordpress loop

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, loops, advanced-custom-fields

Youtube video in a popup keeps playing after the popup is closed. There are multiple videos in popups on the page. The page is a wordpress loop.

I have my code working well just up to this point where I need to stop the video playing.

I am pretty sure that the solution is probably very simple. I have tried various things over the past 2 days and I still just can't get the videos to stop playing when I close the popup box. I have only managed so far to get the first video to stop playing with the commented piece inside my pasted code.

```
<div class="project-box">
    <div id="close<?php the_permalink() ?>"></div>


    <div class="project-box-image">


        <div class="project-box-overlay">
            <div class="project-overlay-links">

                <a id="video-button" href="#<?php the_title(); ?>" class="button-link">Play video</a>
                <a class="button-link" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">View Project</a>
            </div><!---project-overlay-links--> 
        </div><!---project-box-overlay-->


        <div id="<?php the_title(); ?>" class="popup-overlay">
            <div id="popup" class="popup">

                <a class="close"  href="#close<?php the_permalink() ?>">&times;</a>


                <div class="content">


                    <?php if( get_field('pop_up_video') ): ?>
                        <div class="video-embed" >
                        <div id="youtube">
                        <iframe width="800" height="400" src="<?php the_field('pop_up_video'); ?>?autoplay=0&rel=0&enable_js=1" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                        </div><!---youtube-->
                        </div><!---video-embed-->
                    <?php endif; ?>

                    <script>
                        $('.close').click(function(e) {
                            e.preventDefault();
                            //$('iframe').attr('src', '');
                            $('.popup-overlay').addClass('display-none');

                            /*$('.youtube').each(function(index) {
                                $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('src'));
                                return false;
                            });

                        });*/


                        $('a#video-button').click(function(){
                            $('.popup-overlay').removeClass('display-none');

                        });                                         
                    </script>                                       


                </div><!---content-->
            </div><!---popup-->
        </div><!---overlay-->


        <?php the_post_thumbnail('service-box-image'); ?>
    </div><!---project-box-image-->


    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">                     
        <h5><?php the_title(); ?></h5>
    </a>

    <div class="post-tags">
        <?php the_tags('', ', '); ?>
    </div><!---post-tags-->

    <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>

</div><!---project-box-->
```

Comment: I don’t think trying to set the src of those iframes to the value it already has is a good approach in the first place. Apart from that browsers might not feel inclined to reload the iframe in that case to begin with, it also probably creates a rather bad user experience, if I have to restart the video from the beginning should I reactivate that same “popup” again. Using the YT Player API (to _pause_ the video when I leave the popup) would be the right way to go about this. https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Example_Video_Player_Constructors

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you have multiple popups? If so, the code to change the src will affect all dialogs.

I'm assuing you're changing the SRC to stop the video. Also, assuming that the `.close_me` element is within the .hide_overlay element, you can do this:

```
jQuery('.close_me').click(function (e) {
  var $videoEl = jQuery(this).closest('.hide_overlay').find('iframe');
  $videoEl.attr('src', $videoEl.attr('src'));
});
```

This works because `jQuery(this)` will target the specific close button related to that one popup, and not target all popups.

Technically, a nicer way to stop or pause a video is to use the [Youtube Javascript API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) as you can do something like:

```
player.stopVideo();
```